# Storage and efficient lookup for range data

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, range-query

**Problem Statement:**
We will be getting a request of a number (11 digits) and have to efficiently lookup in the database and return a single row (last updated) based on range in which it fits.

**Current DB Structure:**:

Using MySQL

Currently, We have a table which has 2 columns i.e low_range and high_range which stores the range of data and there are 2 other columns which stores corresponding data i.e. is_active (values can 0 and 1) and code (int value which is id of another table i.e code_mapping).

**Table 1 name:** range_mapping

**DB schema:**

```
create table range_mapping (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`low_range` decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
`high_range` decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
`is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`code` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_comp_is_active_low_high_range` (`is_active`, `low_range`, `high_range`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26891234 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Table 2 name:** code_mapping

**DB schema:**

```
create table code_mapping (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `nameIdx` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4410 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Query to be optimized**:
I need to redesign or optimize the query for efficient and faster execution.

**Request:** 12345678912

**Possible rows in table:**

```
low_range: 12345678901 high_range: 12345678913
low_range: 12345678910 high_range: 12345678912
low_range: 12345678902 high_range: 12345678920
```

```
select a.low_range, a.high_range, b.name from range_mapping AS a 
LEFT JOIN code_mapping AS b ON a.code = b.id 
WHERE a.is_active = 1 and 12345678912 BETWEEN a.low_range AND a.high_range 
ORDER BY a.id DESC 
limit 1;
```

**Issue:**:
When executing above query with 20 requests/sec, it is taking up to ~20 sec. I need to optimize the query or database to make it execute within 500 ms.

I already added the composite index which somehow optimized the query and also used force index as part of query. It is still taking more than 2 sec.

**Explain query:**

```
explain select a.low_range, a.high_range, b.name from range_mapping AS a force index(idx_comp_is_active_low_high_range) LEFT JOIN code_mapping AS b ON a.code = b.id WHERE a.is_active = 1 and 12345678912 BETWEEN a.low_range AND a.high_range ORDER BY a.id DESC limit 1;
```

**Output:**

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: a
type: range
possible_keys: idx_comp_is_active_low_high_range
key: idx_comp_is_active_low_high_range
key_len: 11
ref: NULL
rows: 227190
Extra: Using index condition; Using filesort

***************************
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: b
type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 4
ref: testbackup.a.code
rows: 1
Extra: Using where
```

**Expectation:**
How can I improve the database schema or optimize the query to fetch the data within ms.

Comment: Could you try adding range_mapping.id at the end of `idx_comp_is_active_low_high_range` index? That could get rid of the filesort in the explain

Comment: This has been already tried. However, It didn't improve the performance when concurrent hits were done of 30 db queries/sec.

Comment: See [_IP ranges_}(https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges) for a very efficient approach that might work for you.  (Your low/high_range works like IP addresses.)

Comment: @RickJames Let me check and confirm

Answer (score 1):

You are seeking the matching row for the *largest* value of `a.id` (from `ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 1)` that matches your query filters. That means you can rewrite your query like this.

Let's start with a subquery.

```sql
SELECT MAX(id) id 
  FROM range_mapping 
 WHERE is_active = 1
   and low_range <= 12345678912
   AND high_range >= 12345678912
```

This subquery does the hard work. It has to look for a lot of stuff in your table, so simplifying it is good.

It can be accelerated with this compound index.

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_comp_is_active_low_id_high_range ON range_mapping
    (is_active, low_range, id DESC, high_range)
```

To satisfy the subquery MySQL will random-access this index to the first eligible row according to the first two columns (`is_active` and `low_range`). Then it will scan through the index looking for the first index row matching your `high_range` criterion, and return the `id` value from that index entry. It's already the largest one.

Notice that the index I defined is almost the same as the one you have, except for the addition of `id` as the second-to-last column.

Next, we need to use that `range_mapping.id` value to retrieve the details from the first table and the `name` from the second table. That goes like this.

```sql
SELECT a.low_range, a.high_range, b.name
  FROM (
        SELECT MAX(id) id 
          FROM range_mapping 
         WHERE is_active = 1
           AND low_range <= 12345678912
           AND high_range >= 12345678912
       ) AS found
  JOIN range_mapping AS a ON found.id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN code_mapping AS b ON a.code = b.id
```

This should be faster. It doesn't have to sort anything, nor does it have to join more than one row.

You can write it with BETWEEN the same way.

```sql
SELECT a.low_range, a.high_range, b.name
  FROM (
        SELECT MAX(id) id 
          FROM range_mapping 
         WHERE is_active = 1
           AND 12345678912 BETWEEN low_range AND high_range
       ) AS found
  JOIN range_mapping AS a ON found.id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN code_mapping AS b ON a.code = b.id
```

Comment: SELECT MAX(id) id 
  FROM range_mapping 
 WHERE is_active = 1
   and low_range <= 12345678912
   AND high_range >= 12345678912

In the above query, you have used comparison operators and same request number i.e. 12345678912 , but as per the query mentioned in my question, I don't know the lowest and highest range. That's why between was used.

Eg:
There can be a row like this: low_range: 12345678901 high_range: 12345678913
and request: 12345678912 falls in above range. 
However, your query will not fetch this row.

Comment: `12345678912 BETWEEN low_range AND high_range` is equivalent to what I wrote, for what it's worth.  At any rate it doesn't matter to my answer for what it's worth. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot @O. Jones. I executed the above query, it executed in 50-100 ms. But when I did a lot of this query, it is taking an average 686 ms, minimum (159 ms) and max (686 ms), whereas my query is taking an average 87 ms, minimum (22 ms) and max (208 ms).

Load test is done on a 4 core machine with 20 users and duration upto 40 sec.
So, I am not sure which will perform better as data and load will increase eventually.

Comment: Query optimization is as much art as science. It's hard to predict how query execution plans will change as table sizes scale up. That's why database operations people revisit query performance regularly for the life of an application.