# Identical query, indentical schema different databases (data) - one uses index the other does not

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have created this index on 4 different databases hosted on 2 different RDS instances (eu, us).

```
create index CONCURRENTLY foo_index
    on foo (path, bar_id);
```

And I am running this query on all 4 databases:

```
explain analyse WITH anon_1 AS
                 (SELECT bar.id AS id
                  FROM bar
                  WHERE bar.id IN (SELECT max(bar.id) AS max_1
                                                FROM bar
                                                         JOIN baz ON baz.id = bar.baz_id
                                                WHERE baz.bax_uuid = 'd70a2c67-e53e-3f91-b95c-4e9c8142b0df'
                                                  AND baz.error_string IS NULL
                                                  AND baz.end_dttm IS NOT NULL
                                                GROUP BY bar.baz_id))
        SELECT foo.id,
               foo.bar_id,
               foo.created_dttm,
               foo.path,
        FROM foo
        WHERE foo.path = 'some.json'
          AND foo.bar_id IN (SELECT anon_1.id
                                                                FROM anon_1)
        ORDER BY foo.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

For the 2 databases in the EU RDS instance I am seeing it using this new index `foo_index` - which is great:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=11742.51..11742.52 rows=1 width=370) (actual time=4007.724..4007.732 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=11742.51..11742.56 rows=20 width=370) (actual time=4007.723..4007.730 rows=0 loops=1)
        Sort Key: foo.id DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=5507.49..11742.41 rows=20 width=370) (actual time=4007.710..4007.717 rows=0 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (foo.bar_id = bar.id)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=113.26..6343.71 rows=1623 width=370) (actual time=17.257..701.014 rows=326 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: ((path)::text = 'some.json'::text)
                    Heap Blocks: exact=326
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_index  (cost=0.00..112.86 rows=1623 width=0) (actual time=13.768..13.769 rows=326 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((path)::text = 'some.json'::text)
              ->  Hash  (cost=5369.96..5369.96 rows=1941 width=8) (actual time=3305.900..3305.905 rows=479 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 35kB
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4358.01..5369.96 rows=1941 width=8) (actual time=2776.766..3305.222 rows=479 loops=1)
                          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4357.59..4359.59 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=2776.103..2776.653 rows=479 loops=1)
                                Group Key: max(bar_1.id)
                                Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 89kB
                                ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4313.92..4333.33 rows=1941 width=8) (actual time=2775.742..2775.894 rows=479 loops=1)
                                      Group Key: bar_1.baz_id
                                      Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 177kB
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.35..4304.21 rows=1941 width=8) (actual time=6.316..2770.009 rows=1885 loops=1)
                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on baz  (cost=8.05..955.18 rows=473 width=4) (actual time=0.154..15.543 rows=479 loops=1)
                                                  Recheck Cond: ((bax_uuid)::text = '841fec75-6cf8-3985-8167-3da5e12875ea'::text)
                                                  Filter: ((error_string IS NULL) AND (end_dttm IS NOT NULL))
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=349
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_baz_bax_uuid  (cost=0.00..7.93 rows=486 width=0) (actual time=0.088..0.088 rows=541 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: ((bax_uuid)::text = '841fec75-6cf8-3985-8167-3da5e12875ea'::text)
                                            ->  Index Scan using ix_bar_baz_id on bar bar_1  (cost=0.29..7.03 rows=5 width=8) (actual time=2.144..5.742 rows=4 loops=479)
                                                  Index Cond: (baz_id = baz.id)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using bar_pkey on bar  (cost=0.42..5.10 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.101..1.101 rows=1 loops=479)
                                Index Cond: (id = (max(bar_1.id)))
                                Heap Fetches: 266
Planning Time: 17.482 ms
Execution Time: 4007.919 ms
```

Which is great! However when using the same query in the US RDS instances bizarely it just uses an index scan on the pkey and not the key I have added! WHY?

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=17907.82..21582.49 rows=1 width=362) (actual time=585266.498..585266.508 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=17907.82..4063717.43 rows=1101 width=362) (actual time=585266.497..585266.505 rows=0 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (foo.bar_id = bar.id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 853435
        ->  Index Scan Backward using foo_pkey on foo  (cost=0.43..1401929.41 rows=3648 width=362) (actual time=2798.416..584145.159 rows=55 loops=1)
              Filter: ((path)::text = 'some.json'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 16725822
        ->  Materialize  (cost=17907.38..19096.92 rows=48297 width=8) (actual time=12.168..15.860 rows=15517 loops=55)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=17907.38..18855.44 rows=48297 width=8) (actual time=669.205..743.222 rows=15517 loops=1)
                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=17906.96..17908.96 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=669.183..679.325 rows=15517 loops=1)
                          Group Key: max(bar_1.id)
                          Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1569kB
                          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=16442.96..17303.25 rows=48297 width=8) (actual time=655.951..662.484 rows=15517 loops=1)
                                Group Key: bar_1.baz_id
                                Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2833kB
                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=2335.18..13726.26 rows=48297 width=8) (actual time=28.518..633.560 rows=46551 loops=1)
                                      Hash Cond: (bar_1.baz_id = baz.id)
                                      ->  Seq Scan on bar bar_1  (cost=0.00..10971.03 rows=160003 width=8) (actual time=0.008..546.790 rows=159499 loops=1)
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=2138.62..2138.62 rows=15725 width=4) (actual time=28.296..28.298 rows=15517 loops=1)
                                            Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 674kB
                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on baz  (cost=243.25..2138.62 rows=15725 width=4) (actual time=1.079..24.310 rows=15517 loops=1)
                                                  Recheck Cond: ((bax_uuid)::text = 'd70a2c67-e53e-3f91-b95c-4e9c8142b0df'::text)
                                                  Filter: ((error_string IS NULL) AND (end_dttm IS NOT NULL))
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 203
                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=1677
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_baz_bax_uuid  (cost=0.00..239.31 rows=15870 width=0) (actual time=0.864..0.865 rows=16481 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: ((bax_uuid)::text = 'd70a2c67-e53e-3f91-b95c-4e9c8142b0df'::text)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using bar_pkey on bar  (cost=0.42..5.56 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=15517)
                          Index Cond: (id = (max(bar_1.id)))
                          Heap Fetches: 6197
Planning Time: 1.531 ms
Execution Time: 585267.922 ms
```

The only variable is data but all 4 database have different data.

The RDS instances are identical spec and postgres version.

---

## Edit:

I have managed to get it to use the index by removing the order by limit 1 and using `max` instead.

```
WITH anon_2 AS
         (SELECT bar.id AS id
          FROM bar
          WHERE bar.id IN (SELECT max(bar.id) AS max_2
                                        FROM bar
                                                 JOIN baz ON baz.id = bar.baz_id
                                        WHERE baz.bax_uuid = '7e326ae5-adab-35aa-a350-e2be7e06a57e'
                                          AND baz.error_string IS NULL
                                          AND baz.end_dttm IS NOT NULL
                                        GROUP BY bar.baz_id)),
     anon_1 AS
         (SELECT max(foo.id) AS max_1
          FROM foo
          WHERE foo.path = 'some.json'
            AND foo.bar_id IN (SELECT anon_2.id
                                                                  FROM anon_2)
          GROUP BY foo.path)
SELECT foo.id,
       foo.bar_id,
       foo.created_dttm,
       foo.path,
       foo.compressed_data,
       foo.s3_url
FROM foo
WHERE foo.id IN (SELECT anon_1.max_1
                                       FROM anon_1)
```

but strangely the performance is now not as good for rows where there is a matching `path`.

Comment: Different data means different stats and estimations for the planner, which might translate to a different plan. See [this (way simpler) example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77502587/5298879) - exact same structure, exact same amount of rows, but what's in them dictates a different plan, different performance (0.06ms index-only scan downgraded to a 7s seq scan).

Comment: Also, even [minor version difference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/PostgreSQLReleaseNotes/postgresql-versions.html) can affect plans. You can check [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/) for details why. Side-note: I'm guessing the reason was lost to censorship, but can't you move the `select max(bar.id)` subquery from inside the cte, directly to the lowermost `in` where it's supposed to be used, getting rid of the cte entirely? At the moment it looks like you're doing `where a in(select b where b in (select max(c)))` when you can `where a in (select max(c))`

Comment: For instance in EU location, CTE anon_1 generate significant lower rowset (1941) then US location (48297). Case when cardinality of foo_index is lower than this (48297), my bee better use another index (foo_pkey). Its seems that table sizes in locations quite different.

Comment: Try  create additional index ``on foo (bar_id,path )``

Comment: @ValNik I have already created `foo (path,bar_id )` are you saying do the flip?

Comment: I see, need indexes ``on foo (bar_id,path )`` and ``on foo (path,bar_id )``

Comment: @ValNik unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: it is still using the `Index Scan Backward`